# Vertical alignment in Bootstrap 4 using flexbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

wondered if you could help me with this frustrating detail about Bootstrap 4:

I used the code from this page https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment to explore `align-self-start` flexbox alignment. The code that they put in the example doesn't work, however. 
Is there any not very complicated way to make it work using the similar terms? 
Or is this piece of code completely invalid now:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to actually *see* the difference, give the `row` a minimum height.

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col">
      One of three
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      One of three
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought I was going mad for a moment! You are a star :)

Comment: by pressing a green tick, right? Sorry, just joined this site yesterday, still not sure about everything